# What is groupId and artifactId of jar built by Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I built `jar` of project in `Intellij Idea`(`Build`-`Build Artifact`), and I'm trying to add it to another project that uses `Maven`. I have to add it to `pom.xml`, but I need to know groupId, artifactId and version of my `jar`.

Comment: If you just build it by IntelliJ it's probably not in your local maven repository and thus doesn't have any groupId or version (artifactId is probably the name of the jar). If IntelliJ deploys it to some repository (local or not) you'd need to specify that information anyways so you should know them.

Comment: So, how can I add my jar to project, which uses Maven?

Comment: Deploy it manually to your local repository. If you add a dependency to your other project's pom.xml Maven will complain about the missing dependency but the message should contain the command to deploy it properly (the only thing you'd have to add is the path to the jar which you want to deploy).

Comment: Another option is to "mavenize" the project that you want to bring in as a dependency. If it isn't a large project, it shouldn't be that difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you built your first project with maven, in the pom.xml of the project, you have to define your maven coordinates (groupId, artifactId, version). I think in your case, you developed your project without maven. In your second project, which is developed with maven, you should add your first jar file as an external jar file. There is a step by step tutorial on the link below.

[Adding an external Jar file to your project](http://softwarecave.org/2014/06/14/adding-external-jars-into-maven-project/)